# Displaying certain data by comparing a field's ObjectId with another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

What I want to do is if a user is logged in, then that particular user, if a *co-ordinator* then only be able to their project data.

**This is the route handler:**

```js
router.get("/coordinatorsProjects", expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const Projects = await
        CreateProjectModel.find({
            coordinatorName: "61ed96ff001bcd77e5d25ce5"
        });
        /*
            I want to display these only documents to whosoever's id
            matches the `coordinatorName` field.
        */

        res.status(201).send(Projects)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: error.stack
        });
    }
}));
```

**This is the Project model:**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const projectsForm = new mongoose.Schema({

    projectName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    startDate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    endDate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    discription: {
        type: String,
    },

    coordinatorName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    budget: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    pic: {
        type: String,
        default: "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
    },

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ProjectTable', projectsForm);
```

**This is the frontend (React.js) code to provide the user's `_id` to the `coordinatorName` field in a `<select>` tag and then store it: **

```html
<div className="form-group">
    <label className="form-label col">
        Co-ordindator name
    </label>
    <select id="coordinatorName" name="coordinatorName" type="select" className="form-control" value={coordinatorName} onChange={handleInputs}>
        <option value="">Select Coordinator</option>
        {userId &&
        userId.map((user) => (
        <option value={user._id}>
            {user.firstname} {user.lastname}
            {/* COORDINATOR: {user.isCoordinator.toString()} */}
        </option>
        ))}
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: coordinatorName:"61ed96ff001bcd77e5d25ce5" : what is datatype you have defined in model

Comment: @PramodKharade String

Comment: hello.... any one can help me? pls...

Comment: you can contact me on kharade.pramod91@gmail.com . will help you